# In Javascript or jQuery how to scroll so that an element inside another div is centered vertically and horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery or Javascript to auto scroll so that the `.innerElement` is centered `vertically and horizontally` in the `.wrapper` scroll boxes.

Note that the scrollable area has to be inside of a div, it can't use the window viewport (since the final version of this will have multiple scrollable areas).

I tried this:

```js
$('.wrapper')
  .scrollTop($('.innerElement').position().top - ($('.wrapper').height() / 2))
  .scrollLeft($('.innerElement').position().left - ($('.wrapper').width() / 2));
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 5000px;
  height: 5000px;
  position: relative;
}

.innerElement {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  top: 1400px;
  left: 1300px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="innerElement"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't wrap my head around the math on this.

Comment: is the `.positio` just a typo? Also `$('.wrapper').height` is missing the function call -> `$('.wrapper').height()` and in your CSS, there's also a missing `;` between `width` and `height` of ".innerElement"

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a different formula to calculate the required coords:

```
For Top offset: (ElementTop - (WrapperHeight / 2) + (ElementHeight / 2))
For Left offset: (ElementLeft - (WrapperWidth / 2) - (ElementWidth / 2))
```

Also you can make use of the native 'Scroll' method to achieve a smooth transition.

I attach a CodePen with the concept: https://codepen.io/geekzolanos-dev/pen/xxGEmRq